# (asp.net MVC4) Reference a global base model in _layout.cshtml and custom models in other views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two controllers: `HomeController` and `CustomersController` (the 2nd controller has been generated using vs.net add scafolded item dialog)

I created this `base view model` which works with `_layout.cshtml` (to pass data like app name, meta description and other global info that's pulled from DB / changed depending on language set by the user)

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then I derived another `CommonModel` from it:

```
    public class CommonModel: BaseViewModel
```

so that I can use it with my `HomeController()`, ie.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string LocalizedTitle = "Greeting in user language...";
        CommonModel Model = new CommonModel { PageTitle = LocalizedTitle };

        return View(Model);
    }
    ...
```

Then, in `_layout.cshtml`, I have something like this:

```
@model PROJECT_NAME.Models.CommonModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@Model.PageTitle - @Model.AppName</title>
    ...
```

The problem is, this doesn't work if a user tries to access `Customers/Index`, in this case, I'm getting the dreaded error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type`...

Customers/Index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<PROJECT_NAME.Models.Customer>

<h2>Show your list here...</h2>
...
```

My `CustomersController` looks like this:

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Customers
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Customers.ToList());
    }
```

**My question is** How can I make each view call its own model without interfering with each other?

In other words, how can I make `_Layout.cshtml` reference `@model PROJECT_NAME.Models.CommonModel`, while `Customers/Index.cshtml` reference `@model IEnumerable<PROJECT_NAME.Models.Customer>` without having an error?

---

Disclaimer!

1. I'm very new to asp.net MVC, please be nice!
2. Yes, I did look a lot before, but none of the questions/answers I found in SO fix my issue (either that or I didn't understand them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You base view model is `BaseViewModel` (which contains the properties you want ot display in the layout), therefore your `_Layout.cshtml` file should have

```
@model PROJECT_NAME.Models.BaseViewModel // not CommonModel
```

Then all views that use that layout need to use a view model that derives from that base model, so in the case of a view that displays `IEnumerable<Customer>`, the view model for that view would be

```
public class CustomerListVM : BaseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method for that view

```
string LocalizedTitle = "Greeting in user language...";
CustomerListVM model = new CustomerListVM()
{
    PageTitle = LocalizedTitle,
    ... // other properties of BaseViewModel
    Customers = db.Customers
}
return View(model);
```

and the view will then be

```
@model CustomerListVM
....
@foreach(var customer in Model.Customers
{
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks but vs.net is complaining about Customers not being defined in `@foreach(var customer in Model.Customers`, also I was hoping to have something that would play nice with scaffolding...

Comment: Then you did not follow the code in my answer - the line `Customers = db.Customers` assigns the collection and `return View(model)` returns the model containing the populated collection. And what do you mean _play nice with scaffolding_ (your using view models)

Comment: Ahh yes, I typed @model `IEnumerable<CustomerListVM>` in my view. Still it doesn't recognize `@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Customer.Name)` unless I put it in a foreach loop, any idea why/how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand it right.

But you want to use 2 models in your view ?

lets say :

modelA to use for the layout

an ModelB to use in the webpage ?

something like

Actionresult with 2 Models?

if thats right you can do something like this

`List<ModelB>` = ....Fill it

return View(ModelA,ModelB);

Would look like :

```
return View(db.Model.ToList(),ModelB);
```

and in the layout using @Model and for the webpage u can use your ModelB (not as @Model)

This isn't the best option.
But maybe it is a start to helping you.